# openstack image unset --property BadRequestException: 400

Tags: image, properties, openstack, unset, glance

Version **stein** openstack, one image had set the property with `hw_scsi_model='virtio-scsi'`, now I have to unset it, but can't work.

```
# openstack image unset --property hw_scsi_model debian9.5
BadRequestException: 400: Client Error for url: http://10.10.10.10:9292/v2/images/3***0, Bad Request'

# openstack image show debian9.5 -c status -c visibility -c properties
| Field      | Value                                       |
| properties | hw_scsi_model='', os_hash_algo='sha512', ...|
| status     | active                                      |
| visibility | shared                                      |
```

While set the value to `null` or `None`, create server with this image, get error `Field value is invalid`

```
# openstack image set --property hw_scsi_model='' debian9.5
# openstack image show debian9.5 -c properties -f value
{u'owner_specified.openstack.sha256': u'5**', 'hw_scsi_model': u''}
or
{u'owner_specified.openstack.sha256': u'5**', 'hw_scsi_model': u'None'}
```

**error log**:

```
INFO nova.api.openstack.wsgi [req-***] HTTP exception thrown: Invalid image metadata. Error: Field value is invalid
```

How could I unset the property in image?

Answer (score 0):

One solve method by `glance` component sub-command `image-update`:

```
glance image-update --remove-property hw_scsi_model debian9.5
```

> [openstack image unset --property fails](https://storyboard.openstack.org/#!/story/2008463)